# Java Arrays.sort performance for primitive types and objects

Tags: java, performance

I read a few threads here about Arrays.sort using "tuned quick-sort" for primitive types and merge-sort for objects. I did a small test just to prove that but I found is quiet the opposite.

```
            int a[] = new int[50000];
    //Integer a[] = new Integer[50000];

    for(int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
        //a[i] = new Integer(new Random().nextInt(5000)); 
        a[i] = new Random().nextInt(5000);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Arrays.sort(a);

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

For primitive type array it took 22ms where as for array with objects it took 98ms. My laptop it i7 with 8 cores and 8GB of RAM. Have I run it incorrectly?

Many Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is that inconsistent with the expectation? Aside from the indirection for the object costing performance (which makes your benchmark invalid) quick-sort is simply faster than merge-sort.

Comment: What are you trying to proove?

Comment: Doesn't this depend quite a bit on the implementation of the comparators? I assume that the primitive comparator just uses machine integer comparison, but using the Integer object would take more time for a comparison...

Comment: More likely you drew an incorrect conclusion. Accessing objects is more expensive than accessing a primitive due to the extra dereference so you would expect it to be slower.  Also it is much biggest so less likely to fit in your smaller CPU caches

Comment: you should use `System.nanoTime()` and should post proper microbenchmark as a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), and primitives comparision should be faster than object creation, accessing etc..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not surprising to me at all.

First, you have primitives vs. the indirection of needing to chase references down, the comparisons between two primitives will be faster, etc.

Second, a primitive array will play extremely nicely with the CPU cache. A non-primitive array will not necessarily because there is no guarantee that the referenced objects are contiguous in memory (unlikely) and, additionally, the *referrent* objects are larger which means that *less* of them can fit in cache at any one time.

See, in both cases, the values in the *arrays* will fit in the cache, but the problem with the `Integer[]` is that you still have to leave the cache and hit the memory bus to chase down the references and find them in main memory; those references could be pointing all over the place on the heap. This is going to make the poor CPU just wait and wait as *now* cache misses become much more likely.

That is, you have this array of primitives like this

```
  _   _   _   _       _
 |5| |7| |2| |1| ... |4|
```

and these all sit next to each other in memory. When one value is pulled into cache from memory, the neighbors get pulled into the cache too. Quicksort and mergesort operate on contiguous sections of the array, so they benefit *very* much from the CPU cache being nice here (this is [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference))

But when you have an array of `Integer` like this

```
           _               _
     |--->|7|     ______> |1| 
 _   |   _       |   _
| | |_| | | ... |_| | |         _
 |     _ |_____      |________>|4|
 |___>|5|      |    _           
               |__>|2|
```

the storage locations for the *references* are contiguous in memory, so *they* play nicely with the cache. The problem is the *indirection, the possibility of the *referrent* `Integer` objects being fragmented in memory and the fact that *less* of them will fit in the cache. This extra indirection, the fragmentation, and the size issue is what will *not* play nicely with the cache.

Again, for something like quicksort or mergesort which plays on contiguous sections of the array, this is huge, Huge, HUGE and almost surely accounts for the vast majority of the performance difference.

> Have I run it incorrectly?

Yes, please use `System.nanoTime` the next time that you need to do a benchmark. `System.currentTimeMillis` has terrible resolution and is not good for benchmarking.

Comment: Major props to someone with art skills that can make pretty versions of my *primitive* (pun intended!) caveman array artwork.

Comment: `nanoTime` is but one small problem in OP's naïve attempt at benchmarking inside the JVM.

Answer (score 10):

Your int[] fits in your L2 cache.  It is about 4 B * 50K which is 200 KB and your L2 cache is 256 KB.  This will run much faster than your Object[] which will be in your L3 cache as it is about 28 B * 50K or 1400 KB in size.

The L2 cache (~11 clock cycles) is about 4-6x faster than your L3 cache (~45 - 75 clock cycles)

I bet if you ran this more than once you would get a better result as the code warms up.

```
public static void test_int_array() {
    int a[] = new int[50000];
    //Integer a[] = new Integer[50000];

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        //a[i] = new Integer(new Random().nextInt(5000));
        a[i] = random.nextInt(5000);
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("int[] sort took %.1f ms%n", time / 1e6);
}

public static void test_Integer_array() {
    Integer a[] = new Integer[50000];

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        a[i] = random.nextInt(5000);
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Integer[] sort took %.1f ms%n", time / 1e6);
}

public static void main(String... ignored) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (test_int_array()[0] > 0) throw new AssertionError();
        if (test_Integer_array()[0] > 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

prints

```
int[] sort took 32.1 ms
Integer[] sort took 104.1 ms
int[] sort took 4.0 ms
Integer[] sort took 83.8 ms
int[] sort took 33.4 ms
Integer[] sort took 76.7 ms
int[] sort took 4.4 ms
Integer[] sort took 40.5 ms
int[] sort took 3.8 ms
Integer[] sort took 17.4 ms
int[] sort took 4.7 ms
Integer[] sort took 22.4 ms
int[] sort took 4.4 ms
Integer[] sort took 12.1 ms
int[] sort took 3.7 ms
Integer[] sort took 11.2 ms
int[] sort took 3.9 ms
Integer[] sort took 10.7 ms
int[] sort took 3.6 ms
Integer[] sort took 11.9 ms
```

You can see how much difference warming up the code can make.

Comment: I don't think that this is *quite* right. On 32-bit JVM, `int` and the references in the `Integer[]` have the same size; they'll both consume the same amount of cache. The problem is the indirection and that the references still have to be chased out across the memory bus. Since the allocated objects are not necessarily contiguous, that's where the cache difference comes in.

Comment: @Jason even on the 32-bit JVM each Integer has a reference which is 4 bytes, a header which is 12 bytes and a value which is 4 bytes, This is 20 bytes total and every byte matters because they take up space on the cache lines.  On a 64 bit JVM, the reference is still 32-bit (Unless you have 32 GB heap or more) but the header is 16 bytes, 4 bytes for the value and 4 bytes padding as the objects are 8 byte aligned.  When objects are allocated in the Eden space they are typically continuous in memory.  You can see this by using `Unsafe.getInt(array, offset)`

Comment: But the storage locations in the *array* are just the references. The *referrent objects* have the header and what-not that you describe.

Comment: @Jason and they all need to be in memory/cache somewhere.  You can't sort an array of references without looking at the objects.

Comment: I see your point, and I think we're both right. The indirection, the fragmentation, and the larger objects *all* hurt the cache performance.

Comment: One more point: `quicksort` does no heap allocation, whereas merge/timsort does: hence there will be minor GC's occuring during sorting. That also adds a millisecond or two.

Comment: @Peter I ran it and I got the same result as u did, but why does warming up the code make a difference since objects are not in continuous memory and unlike primitives they need to be accessed through cached references?

Comment: It makes a difference to start with because the code is more complicated and difficult to optimise.  Later it is slower due to the access to the caches and size of the data.  I suspect on the first run, the cost of access is not so much higher, meaning it is code optimised away where is spend most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Have I run it incorrectly?

Your benchmarking is quite primitive and it doesn't really establish anything. How does sorting time grow with array size for each case? How much of the difference between primitive sorting and object sorting can be attributed to the different costs of comparing primitives vs. comparing objects? (This would be independent of the performance of the sorting algorithm, but would be attributed to the sorting algorithm by your test.)

As others have noted, if you are timing things that take on the order of tens of milliseconds, you should be using `System.nanoTime`; `System.currentTimeMillis` often has a resolution no better than 10 ms. Simply switching your timing technology, however, won't solve the more serious problems with your tests.